# Find the minimum discerning subset in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a t table, with let's say `field1` and `field2`. `field1` is an identifier of sets and `field2` contains the member of the sets. Now, the question is, how to find out the smallest amount of `field2` values that will uniquely find a given `field1`?

Sample data

```
+------+------+
|field1|field2|
|  1   |   A  |
|  1   |   B  |
|  1   |   C  |
|  2   |   A  |
|  2   |   C  |
|  2   |   D  |
|  3   |   B  |
|  3   |   D  |
+------+------+
```

I am looking for a query which given `1` as an argument returns `(A,B)`, for 2 returns `(A,D)` or `(C,D)` both are good and for `3` returns `(B,D)`. If the generic case is too hard then let's ask: is there such a pair that does this.

Once I have such a pair I can plug it into this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1 
FROM t t1 
INNER JOIN t t2 USING(field1) 
WHERE t1.field2 = 'A' AND t2.field2 = 'B'
```

and get only a single row.

I have tried something like `SELECT field2 FROM t WHERE field2 NOT IN (SELECT field2 FROM t WHERE field1 != 1) and field1 = 1` but this obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write a subquery that returns all pairs of `field2` values for each `field1`. Then use a left join of this with itself, finding pairs that have the same `field2` values, but different `field1`. These then get excluded with the `NULL` check, and you're left with the unique pairs for each `field1`.

```
SELECT subq1.field1, subq1.a, subq1.b
FROM (
    SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2 AS a, t2.field2 AS b
    FROM t AS t1
    JOIN t AS t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field1 AND t1.field2 < t2.field2
) as subq1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2 AS a, t2.field2 AS b
    FROM t AS t1
    JOIN t AS t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field1 AND t1.field2 < t2.field2
) AS subq2 ON subq1.field1 != subq2.field1 AND subq1.a = subq2.a AND subq1.b = subq2.b
WHERE subq2.field1 IS NULL
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ce92/1)

Comment: Since subq1 and subq2 are the same, perhaps put it in a temporary table? BUt OMG this is so much more uglier than I hoped and certainly only covers the two question... what if there would be a field1 that needs 3 of field2 to be identifieable?

Comment: I can't think of an easy way to do it more generally.

Answer (score 0):

I have written below query

```
 SELECT  temp. field1,temp.firstValue,temp.secondValue
 FROM  (SELECT   table1.field1 , table1.field2 firstValue ,table2.field2 secondValue FROM T table2 ,T table1 
    WHERE table1.field1 = table2.field1 AND table2.field2<> table1.field2 AND table1.field2 < table2.field2  

    )  temp
  GROUP BY   temp. field1,temp.firstValue
```

It will give you below pairs

```
field1  firstValue  secondValue
------  ----------  -----------
     1  A           B          
     1  B           C          
     2  A           C          
     2  C           D          
     3  B           D
```

Please let me know if for input `2` pair `(A,C)` and `(A,D)` would be sufficient